# Importing CSV to mysql table and add date to each row using PHP execution time

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo, import-from-csv

I did php code that do all the work of finding CSV files in a given directory and importing each csv file to the right table. The problem  is I a csv file that contains 1M rows! Yes 1M rows :/  So it takes more than 15 mins to import it. This is the ISSUE. How can I improve the execution time?

```
$csv = new SplFileObject($file, 'r');
$csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

// get columns name
$tableColumns = $db->getColumns('daily_transaction');
print_r($tableColumns);

// get line fro csv file  without the first one
foreach(new LimitIterator($csv, 1) as $line){
    $i = 0;
    $data = array();

    foreach ($tableColumns as $Columns) {

        //  print($line[$i]."<br>");
        $data[$Columns] = $line[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    $data['file_name'] = $infoNAME;
    $data['file_date'] = $file_date;

    $insert_id = $db->arrayToInsert('daily_transaction', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: if you have telnet/SSH access you could split the large file up with the split command  `split -l 1000 filename.csv new`  you may also be able to do that via `shell_exec` function

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html <is designed for speed

Comment: @nogad Yes i Know but Load-data will not give me tho possibility to and to  file_date and file_name for each csv file  because each file has  name and date  ' '